# Tapjoyのオファーウォール広告が表示されない

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x

お世話になります。
Tapjoy-SDK(iOS v11.2.0)を使い、オファーウォール広告を表示させたいのですが、いっこうに表示されず困っています。
※cocos2d-xで開発しておりますが、ネイティブ実装により今はiOS版のみ開発中です。

プレイスメントの種類は「User Initiated」にしています。
マニュアルを参考に実装していますが、Tapjoyからのコンソールログには

```
2015-08-24 17:43:45.622 PROJECT_NAME[9904:3070882] [TJLog level: 4] Content request delivered successfully for placement "プレイスメントのコンテンツ名", contentAvailable: 0
```

のように、広告のリクエストには成功しているようですが、contentはゼロ(contentAvailable: 0)となっています。

まず、ログにあるcontentAvailable: 0というのは、「表示する広告がない」ということでしょうか..？
広告表示されるまでに時間がかかるのかな、とも思いましたがすでに2時間ほどこの状態です。

以下に該当箇所のソースを簡単に記します。

```
@interface NativeAD() 
{
@property (nonatomic, retain) TJPlacement *placement;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *tapjoyViewController;

// ボタンが押されたら呼ばれる
-(void)showTapjoyOfferWallAD:(UIViewController*)controller
{
  _placement = [TJPlacement placementWithName:@"プレイスメントのコンテンツ名" delegate:self ];
  _placement.presentationViewController = controller;
  [_placement requestContent];
  _tapjoyViewController = controller;
}
// このデリゲートメソッドは呼ばれない
-(void)contentIsReady:(TJPlacement*)placement
{
  if (_placement.isContentAvailable && _placement.isContentReady)
  {
    [_placement showContentWithViewController:_tapjoyViewController];
  }
}
// このデリゲートメソッドは呼ばれる
-(void)requestDidSucceed:(TJPlacement*)placement
{
NSLog(@" tapjoy request did succeed.);
}
}
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

ご質問からだいぶ時間が経過しているのでもう解決済みかもしれませんが、私も似たようなケースを経験しましたので参考になればと思い、記しておきます。

Tapjoyの管理画面で登録したアプリを選択し、画面左下部の「アプリ設定」をクリックします。
次に、左のメニューの「テストデバイス」を選択します。
表示された画面で、「新規テストデバイス」をクリックし、テスト用の端末情報を設定します（広告IDは取得出来るアプリがAppstoreで入手できますのでそちらを使用してください）。
登録した端末でテストした結果、私のケースでは表示することが出来ました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

自己解決し、そのまま放置してしまっていました。
私の場合は、登録したアイテムのステータスが無効になっていたことが原因でした。
Tapjoyの担当者に連絡し、有効化されることで無事広告が出るようになりました。

Answer (score 0):

コメントより：

> 私の場合は、登録したアイテムのステータスが無効になっていたことが原因でした。 Tapjoyの担当者に連絡し、有効化されることで無事広告が出るようになりました。- [koexuka](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/10822/koexuka)

Comment: 回答に二票あるのでいらないかもしれませんが。。。一応